# MVC view and viewmodel radiobutton group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, attributes, viewmodel, data-annotations

What is the most elegant way to define a group of radiobuttons in MVC5+ view?

Suppose I have a view model like so

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool Value1 {get;set;}
    public bool Value2 {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to render this on an MVC5+ view so its either Value1 or Value2? In WebForms I would put them on one line and define a common GroupName property for them, while in plain HTML I would make a pair of input type=radio and give them a common "name" attribute. What is the best way to do this in MVC using attributes/data annotations?

Thanks

Comment: Radio buttons are for selecting one value from many. You have 2 properties not one. Not clear what your wanting to do but you would need a (say) `string Value` property and the `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Value, "Value1")` and another with `"Value2"`

Comment: I want to choose between Value1 and Value2. If Value1 radio is checked then Value2 radio gets unchecked. I might not be setting up the viewmodel correctly. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You will need to do it as per my first comment - one property (`string` or `enum` of `bool IsValue`) then create 2 radio buttons for the property

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have a class for example "Employee" referenced in the viewmodel class. Then you assign the viewmodel to the view, where you can reference any class within the viewmodel.

The below example would give you two radio buttons which will give you male or female for the "Gender" attribute of your question. So if your question was "What is your gender?" The user then selects Male or Female. Then in the controller you could ask which value the user selected.

Your ViewModel class would be this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
}
```

Your Employee class would be this:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Gender {get; set;}
}
```

Your Controller would be this:

```
using GenderApplication.Models;
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        //whatever you wanted to do with viewModel.Employee.Gender
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Your view would then be:

```
@model GenderApplication.Models.ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Employee.Gender, "Male")
<text>True</text>
<br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model..Employee.Gender, "Female")
<text>False</text>  
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" formaction="@Url.Action("Create")" />
```

Comment: There is no point in having the extra class (completely unnecessary and certainly not _best_). And this wont work at all - how would a value of `"Male"` or `"Female"` bind to a property which is typeof `bool` (and can only accept values of `true` or `false`.

Comment: Rude..Originally i had a bool in there with true or false, but changed it to string, forgot to replace the bool. The extra class isn't quite right, i would use an employee class and a variable called gender but i was rushing the answer during work and thought a newcomer to MVC would benefit from seeing how a class within a class works. Sorry for trying to help a little more than a one liner..

Comment: Pointing out your mistakes is rude?

Comment: No problem, next time I'll give it the down vote it deserved and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add something here

Please add `[BindProperty]` attribute to the property `Gender` incase you are using

```
<input type = radio" name = "ViewModel.Gender" value="Male"> 
<input type = radio" name = "ViewModel.Gender" value="Female">
```

Like this in your `cshtml` to make it work and populate the input model with the value selected for `Gender`